# interpolate based on index values

Tags: python, interpolation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hItHF.png)

```
         data
2.0  0.000009
1.2       NaN
1.0  0.000010
0.2       NaN
0.0  0.000020
```

Above is the dataframe, I am expecting to interpolate the NaN value according to index value, so index 1.2 should be close to index 1.0. However, I have tried 
df.interpolate("index") and df.interpolate("value"), both did not work as expected.
I want to get the output as below:

```
         data
2.0  0.000009
1.2  0.0000098   
1.0  0.000010
0.2  0.000018
0.0  0.000020
```

Comment: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) (or data).

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [0.000009,np.nan, 0.000010, np.nan, 0.000020 ]})

df['value'].interpolate()
```

Output:

```
0    0.000009
1    0.000010
2    0.000010
3    0.000015
4    0.000020
```

Comment: The output is not spaced the same as original index spacing

Answer (score 0):

Set the display precision to 7 as a decimal, and then use ‘slinear’ for interpolation

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
pd.set_option('precision', 7)
str = '''id,data
2.0,0.0000090
1.2,NaN
1.0,0.0000100
0.2,NaN
0.0,0.0000200
'''
data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(str),index_col='id')
data = data.interpolate(method='slinear')
print(data)
```

Comment: I have updated the original question with the expected answer.